# Qooxdoo TreeVirtual only returns expanded nodes as dataModel

Tags: datamodel, qooxdoo

when i do a `this._tree.getDataModel();` in qooxdoo on a treevirtual, i only get back the expanded nodes. How can i get all nodes in the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by my self. The getData() function provides an array of all nodes in the datamodel.

```
var dataModel = this._tree.getDataModel();
var dataArray = dataModel.getData();
```